# UISegmentedControl not scaling with superview

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` which I add to a plain `UIView`. The UIView (superview of the segmented control) is scaled using UIView animation. It's content mode is set to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`. However, the segmented control is not being scaled.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by scaled? Are you changing the frame? or applying a transform? Have you set the autoresizingMask on the control?

Answer (score 0):

the height of UISegmentControll is fixed if you want to scale this control then use transformations like.....

```
YourSegmentControll.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
```